# Laravel registration error, database is connected, but receiving strange error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have connected to my database successfully as I was able to do all of my beginning migrations, users table and password reset etc.

It is my first time running php artisan make:auth
and when I go to register a new user for the laravel application, I get this error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users`
>   where `email` = ma@yahoo.com)

Here is my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=larabiz
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

The answer was quite simple but weird.

run php artisan make:auth. then run php artisan migrate. shutdown your server, restart the server, and then register your first user. This worked for me, so Laravel was not able to add users during registration, without first restarting the server. That took me 5 fresh Laravel installs and three hours of work! I was in tears :).

Comment: If this is linux, from the root directory, do `grep -R homestead *`. Or check all `database.php` config files to see where `homestead` may be hiding.

Comment: It is a database connection error. Eventually bad username/password.

Comment: Your database username and password are different from what is mentioned in the error? Why is that?

Comment: if username and password are incorrect how can migrate database as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1):

The answer was quite simple but weird.

run php artisan make:auth. 
then run php artisan migrate. 
shutdown your server, restart the server, and then register your first user. This worked for me, so Laravel was not able to add users during registration, without first restarting the server. That took me 5 fresh Laravel installs and three hours of work! I was in tears :).

Comment: restarting what server?

Comment: I shut down xampp and restarted my git bash. There was no problem with my database connection, I have literally started and completed close to 100 Laravel applications, so I am well aware of how to connect to my database with .env. When you run php artisan make:auth, you must restart your server. I found the answer on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIRzJgxhgYo&t=87s. Start watching at 7 minutes 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Did yout try to reload config ?

`php artisan config:clear`

or clear cache ?

`php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `config/database.php` and under `connections` set the values for your connection manually.